spring + swagger = /swagger-resources/configuration/ui 404 NOT FOUND
I followed this excellent example to add swagger and its UI to our old spring project:  Swagger REST API documentation with Spring Boot
It seems to have worked in that when I start the app I can hit my API, and in the logs I see:
2024-06-28T11:19:40,347Z INFO  main o.s.b.a.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver [] => Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path ''
2024-06-28T11:19:40,410Z INFO  main o.s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping [] => Mapped "{[/ping],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2024-06-28T11:19:40,413Z INFO  main o.s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping [] => Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2024-06-28T11:19:41,094Z INFO  main o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [] => Mapped URL path [/swagger-ui.html] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2024-06-28T11:19:41,094Z INFO  main o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [] => Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2024-06-28T11:19:41,287Z INFO  main o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter [] => Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@71c3b41: startup date [Fri Jun 28 13:19:14 CEST 2024]; root of context hierarchy


When I hit http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html#
I just get an emtpy swagger UI thus:

I notice a 404 error in the console: http://localhost:8081/swagger-resources/configuration/ui NOT FOUND
and in the log files:
2024-06-28T12:14:05,456Z WARN  http-nio-8081-exec-7 o.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound [correlationToken:9a9d9be9-71e6-4518-b591-37dad795ed44] => No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/swagger-resources/configuration/ui] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Note:

I'm running from within Intellij, I'm not deploying jars to a server.
I tried new version of springfox (3.0.0) but this gave build error:   Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: and I could not find a solution for this so downgraded to alder version.

How does one configure swagger to find the APIs in the application?
This is what we have:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}

public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("my api")
                .description("description")
                .version("VERSION")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url")
                .license("LICENSE")
                .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com")
                .build();
    }
}

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

NOTE: I tried newer versions of springfox and got build errors.
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebApi {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
       return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapterExtension();
    }
        
    private final class WebMvcConfigurerAdapterExtension implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {            
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(System.getenv("ALLOWED_ORIGIN"));
        }
        
        @Override
        public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.setDefaultTimeout(getResponseTimeout());
            configurer.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("async"));
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new ResponseLogger());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/accounts/findCustomers")
    @ResponseBody
    DeferredResult<List<String>> findCustomers(@RequestAttribute("id") Integer id, @RequestBody String body,
            @RequestHeader String brandId) {
:
:

NOTE: this post: swagger 2.6.1 /swagger-resources/configuration/ui 404
has similar issue, but none of the listed suggestions worked in my case.

OK, found the solution: use 2.8.0 of both dependencies. It was a bug they fixed in the prev. versions.
